# Custom annotation vector with tsmp R package

Tags: r, package

I'd like to use a custom annotation vector (av) for a matrix profile (mp) produced using the tsmp package, but I am unsure how to amend said profile produced by e.g. the compute function.

I note that the package provides some functions to do this for "standard" cases, such as av_complexity, av_hardlimit_artifact etc. and then av_apply, but I want to apply a custom av. I have tried directly replacing the mp in the results produced by compute, i.e.

```
result <- compute( data , ... )
result$mp <- my_av_mp
```

but this doesn't work as I get the following error

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(matrix_profile$mp, min_idx) : 
undefined columns selected
```

Trying

```
result$mp[,1] <- my_av_mp
```

doesn't give an error, but when I try to use the amended result further, i.e.

```
motif_results <- find_motif( result , n_motifs = 5 , ... )
```

I get the error

```
Error in apply(.mp$mp, 2, which.min) : dim(X) must have a positive length
```

What is the correct way to apply a custom av with the tsmp package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

1. create an annotation vector with the same size as the matrix profile (d_size - w_size + 1)

```
my_mp_obj$av <- my_annotation_vector
```

2. Add the proper class to the object:

```
class(my_mp_obj) <- tsmp:::update_class(class(my_mp_obj), "AnnotationVector")
```

3. Apply the annotation vector to the matrix profile:

```
new_mp_with_applied_av <- tsmp::av_apply(my_mp_obj)
```

Comment: Can I suggest that this approach for creating a custom av be part of the official tsmp package and documented accordingly?

Comment: tsmp will be refactored soon, so I guess this will be part of it.